# WebKit force full garbage collection / behaviors & debugging / detecting leaks

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection, webkit

I'm looking for memory leaks in this Cocoa / WebKit app. I am passing objects from native to javascript, and by looking at their lifetimes, I am noticing unpredictable behavior with regards to garbage collection.

I mark each object with an incrementing ID, and keep track of how many objects have been created / freed (garbage collected).

The first ~1000 objects allocated get freed pretty quickly after they're used, and the # of outstanding objects remains very low, around 10. Some random objects (#171 for example) just never seem to get freed.

After that, objects linger around and don't get freed often at all. That object #171 never seems to get collected (after waiting around for an hour watching logs), yet other identically-treated objects get deleted relatively quickly.

None of this proves there are memory leaks, yet it also doesn't confirm that there are none.

So, I have a couple questions:

- How do I force a FULL garbage collect in WebKit? I want to see if I have memory leaks. I tried [`JSGarbageCollect(globalContext)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/JavaScriptCore/Reference/JSBase_header_reference/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/JSGarbageCollect), but it seems to have no effect. It doesn't free any objects -- ones that are later freed seemingly by the GC.
- Is there any way to tell if an object has refs to it?
- Are there any hooks into WebKit's GC, for example even to just know when it runs, or get some insight / statistics?
- Is there any documentation on behaviors of the WebKit GC behavior? Or what debugging tools are available? I understand it is supposed to be a black box, but there should be some basic introspection tools.